# Index out of Range despite check

Tags: python, indexing, range

```
    t = [1, 2, 3]
def cumsum(t):
    t2 = []
    total = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(t): 
        total += t[i]
        t2[i].append(total)
        i += 1
    return t2

cumsum(t)
```

This code takes the sum of the first two list integers and appends it to another list.
I feel like this should logically work and I don't understand why it is producing an index error if i < len(t) when len(t)= 3. So ideally t2 =[1, 3, 6]
while the iterator is less than len(t) (which is 3) add the list item to the total variable then append the total to the new list then iterate.

Comment: From this line `t2[i].append(total)` remove `[i]`. `t2` is empty list at the beginning, so indexing it with `0` produces IndexError.

Comment: to append an element to t2 you don't need to reference it by index. just do t2.append(total)

Comment: `t2[i]` does not exist, just append without indexing.

Comment: Also, to `append` something to `t2[i]`, `t2[i]` would have to be a list itself. If `t2[i]` already existed, you would have to change its value with `t2[i] = total`.

Comment: To put it another way, you check that i is a valid index for t but **not** for t2.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using index `i` to access `t2` list that is empty. To append an element to a list you should use `<list>.append(<element>)`, that is `t2.append(total)` in your case.